# How to point to N (runtime defined number) bytes in the middle of something bigger?

Tags: c++, pointers

The case is that I have a big set of binary data loaded in memory and need to perform bitwise operations between a N bytes length block of data and a N bytes chunk from the middle of this big set.

My first thought is to somehow get a pointer to N chars and then change it to point to start of the chunk. Pseudo code for what I intended to do:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        unsigned int n = getBlockLength(), x = getChunkStartPos(), s = getBinarySetLength();
        char *binary_set;
        char (*chunk_ptr)[n]; //Let's suppose n = 5
        //char block[n] = {'s', 'm', 't', 'h', 'g'};

        binary_set = malloc(s);
        fillBinarySet(binary_set, s); //Let's suppose s = 15 and binary_set is now filled with {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'}
        chunk_ptr = &binary_set + x;

        std::cout << *chunk_ptr << std::endl; //should print "efghi"

        //actually would do something like this:
        //result = block & *chunk_ptr;

        return 0;
}
```

This of course won't compile and the array of characters is just an example, as I did already said it would actually be a big set of binary data. Even if it would compile, I'm not sure of how system would know `chuck_ptr` points to `n` bytes (it searches for null character - that I can't put inside `binary_set` just for this purpose - when dealing with `char`, but what in the case of an array of `bool`s?)...

By "big" I mean something between 125MB and 1000MB. It most likely will be just memory mapped (`mmap()`) from a file instead of fully loaded into memory but RAM consumption is expected to be almost the same, as entire set will be subject to frequent read and write operations. Referred `block` (and chunk) is supposed to be commonly between 1B and 5MB length.

Any thoughts on the fastest and less CPU and RAM intensive way to achieve this goal, please? This is the core of an already heavy application and the only working solutions (e.g.: looping over the binary data set byte by byte from start to the end of the chunk) I could develop don't suit performance requirements. :(

I just want some idea or direction, not asking you to do my job for me. If that is not possible with C or C++, I would like to get pointed to some solution in other high performatic, compiled, language. Thanks so much.

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `char * chunk_start = block + chunk_start_pos;` and a `char * chunk_end = chunk_start + chunk_length;`?

Comment: I don't understand how would I use `chunk_end` for delimiting the chunk being used in bitwise operation against `block`. I have something like this on the disapproved solution in which I loop `binary_set` from `chunk_start` to `chunk_end`.

Comment: You'd loop from `chunk_start` to `chunk_end`, applying the bitwise operation you want to?

Comment: This is how I have today and don't suit performance and time requirements.

Comment: `malloc` is your slow down.  You need to re-write `malloc` (`mymalloc`).  Do what linux does and preallocate a massive chunk of memory and manage it as a memory pool.

Comment: "This is what I have today" -- What, exactly, do you have today?  It's not what you have posted here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @jnbbender, I'll check this as a possible improvement, but my problem is with `chunk_ptr`, not `binary_set`...

Comment: @Donnie I have an implementation that loops from start to the end of the `binary_set`'s chunk while performing the operations. But as I said, it doesn't suit performance and time requirements (take too much time in the loop, because of the size of `binary_part` and the chunks.

Comment: If your operation is complex and you're doing it over enough data, it's going to take time.  That's why I asked to see your current actual solution.

Comment: Yes, I know it, @Donnie. What I don't want is to get some solution that will increase the time it takes. Not that the operation is complex and take much time by itself... this is part of a network application, it needs to answer for the requests the fastest possible.

Comment: Hint, if your doing if this between a fiber network and ethernet network, we couldn't get it working either.  We had to slow down the Fiber network drivers in Linux. :)